# mod_rewrite by user agent not working?

Tags: .htaccess, user-agent

I want to achieve the following, if someone enters site with Android/iPhone user agent, I want to rewrite all his urls to a directory, so for example:

```
user enters -> user served
example.com -> example.com/mobile
example.com/review/12 -> example.com/mobile/review/12
```

I have the following example code snippet in my .htaccess, but it's not working...

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} Android
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ mobile/$1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding the following to your htaccess file in the root directory of your site.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} Android [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/mobile [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ mobile/$1 [L]
```

If you want to change what the user sees in their browser address bar, change the last line to

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ mobile/$1 [L,R]
```

Comment: tried the root directory with an android user agent and got served the root directory (i have a mobile directory with index.php).

Comment: @ItaiSagi, root directory does not have a trailing slash :-), so edited to make it optional above